# Reading newly created entity from object context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have ObjectContext and entity, let's call it Device.
Entity key of entity is not autogenerated, and is specified during adding to context.
After adding of new entity with following code

```
Context.Devices.Add(new Device{Id = someVal, /*initialization*/});
```

I am trying to read that entity

```
var dev = Context.Devices.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == someVal);
```

and getting null.

Of course, after calling of SaveChanges() I can read that device from DB.

Why I can't read entity from context?

Answer (score 2):

Because until you call SaveChanges it does not actually exist in the database. Your call to `Context.Devices.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == someVal);` is making a call back to the database.

Comment: I was expecting that entity should exist in object set in context, and querying against context returns that entity. And in some other cases i was experiencing that behavior

Comment: Hmm. I would check the Context.Devices collection via the debugger to see if the object you just added is showing in there... Maybe using Find in place of SingleOrDefault would work.